# Changing button text after signing in to "Sign Out"

Tags: javascript, c#

I have HTML code of a sign in button:

```
<a href="Login.aspx" id="signin" runat="server" class="navbar-btn btn-success btn right">
    Sign In
</a>
```

and a C# if statement that checks whether you are connected. If yes, I want to change the button text to `Sign Out`.

I tried to use the id of the HTML button `signin` in C# with `signin.Attributes` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

signin.InnerText = "Sign Out!";

Comment: Thank you , it helped :) But do you know how can I change the class of the button after the button's text changed to sign out? I am using Bootstrap and therefore I want to change the class name instead of green button to a red button.

Comment: signin.Attributes["class"] = "className"; OR
            signin.Attributes.Add("class", "className");